# How to create multiple rows in SQL based on condition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Here is the situation:

- We're currently trying to migrate customers from old to new contracts and need to create an automated import for the new contracts (as a csv export, based on a databse calculation).
- The "old" contracts of the customer contain a different product structure than it is needed for the new ones.
- Basically we have to decide - based on the current products and licence numbers, how the new structure should look like and I need some help on how I can do that in SQL.
- In the old structure you could have a product with 5 or even 10 licences
- In the new structure there's only the option to have the MAIN product with 2 licences and all other licences have to be booked in a seperate contract_line as a "Additional" product.

let me show what I mean...

[image]

Any idea on how to create a new line, based on a condition for the number of licences ?
I'm totally clueless.

Thanks for your help in advance.

P.S.: I'm using Amazon Redshift for it.

Comment: Redshift is for timely SQL on Big Data.  It makes no sense to use it in any other situation, because it comes with a considerable range of constraints and restrictions upon its use.  Do you have more a terabyte of contract data?  my guess woud be not, and if not, you very likely should be using Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem is calculating the number of licenses of the two types given your business rules.  One method is to use aggregation:

```
select customerId, 8888 as contractid, 'New Main Product' as product,
       greatest(2, licenses)
from old
where product = 'Old Main Product'
union all
select customerid, 8888 as contractid, 'New Additional Product',
       ( greatest(0,
                sum(case when product = 'Old Main Product' then licenses else 0 end) - 2
                 ) +
         sum(case when product = 'Old Additional Product' then licenses else 0 end)
       )
from old
group by customerid
having sum( (product = 'Old Additional Product')::int ) > 0 or
       sum( licenses ) > 2;
```